# the meaning of "as saying that"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

what does the term **as saying that** mean in sentences below?

> Socrates is represented in Plato's Apology **as saying that** if the state spares his life on condition that he no longer teach as he has been doing, he will not obey.

Ethics - William K.Frankena.

Comment: as saying = as one who says; Socrates is said to say that...

Comment: Is it a custom on the ELL stack exchange to post answers as comments instead of answers?

Comment: I don't have time to go into the grammar of it, hence the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "represent" is to show, to create an image or picture.

When we say that *A represents B **as** VERBing* we mean that in the image of B which A gives us, B *is VERBing*.

> In the picture of Socrates which Plato's *Apology* gives us, Socrates says that if the state spares his life on condition that he no longer teach as he has been doing, he will not obey.

A may also represent B **as** a *NOUN* or **as** *ADJECTIVE*, meaning that in A's image, B is *NOUN* or is *ADJECTIVE*

> Plato represents Socrates as a hero ... *In Plato's image of Socrates, Socrates is a hero.*
>
> Plato represents Socrates as courageous... *In Plato's image of Socrates, Socrates is courageous.*